# Swift navigation bar not appearing

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

I’m new to Swift. Currently trying to build a test app.

My tab nav bar won't appear when i preview the app. When in preview, i can click it and switch between pages, but i can't see it. Created a storyboard with a tab bar controller and view controllers.

Code below. Can't upload images sadly due to being new.

`

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Login_PageApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                WTF_Home()
                WTF_Guides()
                WTF_Guides2()
                WTF_Book()
                WTF_Help()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried looking up solutions but have had no success. Must guides on navigation fixes are from years ago. Ideally i need guides / fixes from 2022.

I've even tried using the 'Navigation Controller' in the storyboard because people suggested it, no success there either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also I'm confused with what's happening in your post. Are you developing an app in SwiftUI or with Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Add the modifier `.tabItem{Image(systemName: "whatever_image")}` to each of the pages in your `TabView`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is complete professional example how you can add tabbar into you application. First Make a separate tabbar controller and then call it from WindowGroup{} which is the start point for you application.

> Tabbarcontroller.swift

```
struct TabBarControllerView: View {
    
    @State private var tabSelection = 0
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .gray
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(ImageName.home.rawValue)
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                    
                }
                .tag(0)
            
            DailyCheckListView()
            
                .tabItem {
                    
                    VStack {
                        Image(ImageName.checkList.rawValue)
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("CheckList")
                    }
                    
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            
            GratitudeJournalView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(ImageName.journal.rawValue)
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Journal")
                    }
                    
                }
                .tag(2)
            
            TDLHostingView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(ImageName.TDL.rawValue)
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("ToDoList")
                    }
                    
                }
                .tag(3)
            
        }
        .accentColor(Color(ColorName.titleColor.rawValue))
        
    }
}
}

struct TabBarControllerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabBarControllerView()
    }
}
```

Now you need to call the TabBarControllerView() from your application @main file.

**Note** just need to add single navigationView at start of your application which will automatically work for each view in tabbar.

> Login_PageAapp.swift

```
import SwiftUI
    @main
struct Login_PageApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                TabBarControllerView()
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated, Qazi! It worked perfectly! Where would you say has the best documentation and guides for Swift? Apple created documentation?

Comment: Actually apple documentation just explain the working of each individual component. If you want to learn about profession design patterns then you can watch lectures of Caio Zullo on YouTube.

Comment: This setup causes endless navigation bugs

Comment: could you please explain in more detail about the issue.